# Slack bot create request URL for incoming thread messages

Tags: slack-api

I am setting up a Slack bot to send messages on a Slack channel. When people respond on the bot's messages via a thread I want it to POST the message to a request URL but I can't seem to find a way to do that.

I am aware how it works with messages sent to channels and direct messages but not threads.

Does Slack API support this?

The only way I've seen is through the `conversation.list` method but I need a way to know when the bot has received a message via threads without doing something like polling. It needs to be Realtime.

Answer (score 0):

After some more reading I found the Event subscriptions API, https://api.slack.com/apis/connections/events-api, and there you can add `message.channels` event and it will POST all replies in threads to the URL you supply.